# list indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, string, list, integer, indices

```
class targil4(object):
    def plus():
        x=list(raw_input('enter 4 digit Num '))
        print x
        for i in x:
            int(x[i])
            x[i]+=1
        print x

    plus()
```

this is my code, I try to get input of 4 digits from user, then to add 1 to each digit, and print it back. When I run this code i get the massage:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
['1', '2', '3', '4']
  File "C:/Users/Maymon/PycharmProjects/untitled4/targil4.py", line 1, in <module>
class targil4(object):
  File "C:/Users/Maymon/PycharmProjects/untitled4/targil4.py", line 10, in   targil4
    plus()
  File "C:/Users/Maymon/PycharmProjects/untitled4/targil4.py", line 6, plus
  int(x[i])
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: `i` is already each value in your list. Doing `x[i]` is incorrect Make use of printing out what is going on in your loop to further understand, and revisit your lesson plan on loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you may get more out of an answer here by actually looking at each statement and seeing what is going on.

```
# Because the user enters '1234', x is a list ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
# each time the loop runs, i gets '1', '2', etc.
for i in x:
    # here, x[i] fails because your i value is a string.
    # You cannot index an array via a string. 
    int(x[i])
    x[i]+=1
```

So we can "fix" this by adjusting the code by our new understanding.

```
# We create a new output variable to hold what we will display to the user
output = ''
for i in x:
    output += str(int(i) + 1)
print(output)
```

Comment: @idjaw Good catch. That's what I get for writing hastily. :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) and do

```
y = [int(i) + 1 for i in x]
print y
```

Comment: @idjaw oops, I must have been misnaming it for a while now, how embarrasing... thanks for correcting me